# remove dot and double dot from result php

Tags: php

i am using below code for directory list it is work as i think but it have little issue when out put it show dot and double dot is there any way to ignore this

code

```
$myDirectory='C:\UniServer\www\list';
$files = scandir($myDirectory);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
echo   $myDirectory.'\\'.$value.'<br>';
}
```

**out put**

```
.
..
0-9.txt
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
f.txt
g.txt
i.txt
j.txt
k.txt
l.txt
m.txt
n.txt
o.txt
p.txt
q.txt
r.txt
s.txt
t.txt
u.txt
v.txt
w.txt
x.txt
y.txt
z.txt
```

**thanks u_mulder i converted in function now**

```
function folder_list($myDirectory) {
$files = scandir($myDirectory);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
    if ($value != '.' && $value != '..')
        echo   $myDirectory.'\\'.$value.'<br>';
}        
}
```

Comment: Use `array_diff($files, [".", ".."])` or `preg_grep("/^(?!\.)/", $files)` or a plain `if ($value != "..")` in the loop.

Comment: Remove the first two elements: `$files = array_slice($array, 2):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($files as &$value) {
    if ($value != '.' && $value != '..')
        echo   $myDirectory.'\\'.$value.'<br>';
}
```